# Позиционирование фона CSS

Tags: css, css3

Есть следующий макет - http://prntscr.com/fxhby1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Синий фон нужно спозиционировать так чтобы на его фоне была надпись войти, 
пробовал сделать через `linear-gradient`, но проблема в том что при увеличении или уменьшении экрана блок перемещается, то влево то в право. - `background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 70%, #2a7fe0 30%)`.

Так же пробовал сделать псевдо селектор для контейнера, но проблема в том что слайдер не входит в контейнер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не понял в какой контейнер не входит слайдер, но псевдоселектором сделать можно так:

```css
header {
  height: 300px;
  background: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}

header:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 80px;
    background: #2a7fe0;
}

.centered {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  min-height: 200px;
  margin: -250px auto 0 auto;
  background: #999;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="centered">test</div>
```